# In MySQL, what is the difference between CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARSET utf8 and CREATE DATABASE dbname DEFAULT CHARSET utf8?

Tags: mysql

What does it change to add the keyword DEFAULT ? I can't figure out and the [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html) just says that

> The CHARACTER SET clause specifies the default database character set

Does that mean that DEFAULT is useless ?

PS : Sorry for my english, not my mother tongue.

Comment: basic tip: anything in mysql syntax examples that's contained in `[]` is OPTIONAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is useless. It's just for semantics, but you can leave it out just as for instance 'outer' in 'left outer join'.